# What is System.String exactly in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I maintain some pretty old Delphi code that in a specific unit uses `EmptyString`.

The compiler resolves it as

> costant EmptyString = '' - from System.string

now i have no System.string.pas file in my hard disk, or .dcu so i am not able to know more about this.

I found in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\source\rtl\sys\system.SysUtils.pas
```

another similar constant:

```
{ Empty string and null string pointer. These constants are provided for
  backwards compatibility only.  }

  EmptyStr: string = '';
{$IFNDEF NEXTGEN}
  NullStr: PString = @EmptyStr;
```

At first sight it seems that `EmptyStr` and `EmptyString` were used in past only so they are *somehow deprecate* so better to use `''` directly or define constants in the application that redefine them.

Now after upgrading a 3rd party component i realized that `EmptyString` is not resolved anymore.

My question is:
what is `System.String` exactly? Why there is no a corresponding .pas file in rtl?

I googled without success.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't remember ever having read `System.string` but it probably is just Delphis built-in `string` type. The relevant code is partially in the System.pas unit and partially built into the compiler.

Comment: System.string the *type* string **in *unit* System**. It is not a class or anything, it is a built-in type, a special type for the compiler and managed by the runtime. This article describes it a little better (together with PChar): ["PChars: no strings attached"](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html).

Comment: @Uli: I have. You'll see it in error messages and the like (e.g. `Incompatible types: 'System.string' and 'System.Integer'` or similar) and in RTTI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`System.String`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.String) is the type [`String`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.String) officially defined in the [`System`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System) unit.

The `string` type is in fact an alias to the [`System.UnicodeString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeString) type. The documentation says it is defined as:

> ```
> type String = UnicodeString;
> ```

In turn the documentation for `UnicodeString` says:

> ```
> type UnicodeString = { built-in type };
> ```

There is no Pascal code to define the type, since it is a *built-in* or *intrinsic* type. All built-in types are officially regarded as being declared in the `System` unit, even though you cannot see their declarations in the Pascal source code for that unit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So EmptyString is somehow a "hidden constant"? Is it advisable not to use it?

Comment: No, `EmptyString` is not defined in the Delphi RTL. If your code that refers to it does compile then your code must define `EmptyString`. On the other hand `EmptyStr` is defined in the `System.SysUtils` unit as you have noticed. Your question was about the type `System.String`. Don't get confused between types, and variables and constants.

Comment: I already did explain that. Sentence no. 2 in my previous comment.

Comment: Yes sorry. Now i got it.  I realize that for any string in Delphi the hint says "System.String"! Thanks a lot, you clarified my doubt and helped me to learn more about rtl.